# main function in django web service

Tags: python, django, web-services

I am preparing a web service using `django` in python. When I start web service, I would like to have a main function to run. However, code below did not work in web service. I want to have an initializer function which will fill the structures defined global. I can achieve it by directly defining an init function and call it end of the module but I don't know whether this is the proper way of doing so.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095155/django-app-initalization-code-like-connecting-to-signals) similar question was posted. As I understand there is no clear solution for that and I find my way to do this. I defined a dummy function in web service module like:

```
def warmup(request):
   response = HttpResponse()
   response.write("ok")
   return response
```

We start application with command `sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081` so I add a piece of code in `manage.py` such that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import requests
import threading
import time


def warmup_request():
    print "warmup.."
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        r = requests.get("http://localhost:8081/warmup/")
        if r.content == "ok":
            return

    except Exception, e:
        pass

    threading.Timer(0,warmup_request).start() 




if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    warmup_request()

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

If `warmup` service API returns `ok` it means loading initial data process has finished. By defining a global flag, we can block all other service API requests before warming up has finished. Or instead defining global flag we may use `request_started` signal stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished) to block all incoming requests with more little effort.

Comment: it's not usual to have a `__main__` function in a Django app

Comment: when do you need this code to execute? when django application is loaded? each request?

Comment: I will have some structures defined globally and will initialise them at the beginning of the service. This global structures will store some data, which will be used by service functions but I need to initialise them at first.

Comment: Did you achieved it?